# Mapping python dictionary to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Suppose I have a very large pandas dataframe.

```
(Pdb) >? responseDF
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [MTG_DEAL_NAME, CV_VOLATILITY_90D, TICKER, NAME, CRNCY, BASE_CRNCY, SETTLE_DT,...]
```

Now, suppose I also have a dictionary with only some of those values:

```
(Pdb) >? fieldvalues
{'NAME': 'MyName', 'CPN': '5', 'MATURITY': '2050-11-01', 'TICKER': 'MyComp'...},
```

Is there an easy way to insert the value of the dictionary into the appropriate column and leave the missing values as "NA" or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `append` method:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1],
    'B': [2]
})

d = {'A': 2}

df.append(d, ignore_index=True)
#     A   B
#0  1.0 2.0
#1  2.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
d={'NAME': 'MyName', 'CPN': '5', 'MATURITY': '2050-11-01', 'TICKER': 'MyComp'}
df=pd.concat([df,pd.Series(d).to_frame().T],axis=1)
```